# Is there a more concise way to do this in Java 8 - Map manipulation

Tags: java, lambda, collections

A very common operation on maps of collections is to create a new collection with an initial value when the key is not present, or if the key is present, do some function on the existing collection. Take for example a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, if the key is not there, create a Set with an initial value of 1. If the key is there, add the value map.size()+1 to the set (or replace this function with some other simple one-liner operation). In Java 7, it's straightforward with if/else, but pretty verbose. I can only come up with the below code for Java 8, which isn't much better (actually worse due to more lines of code). Is there a way to make this more concise?

```
public void process(Map<String, Set<Integer>> m, String key) {
    m.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
            v = new HashSet<>();
            v.add(1);
            return v;
        } else {
            v.add(v.size() + 1);
            return v;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this just a made up example? Why would you keep a set of contiguous integers? There is no point storing `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` when you can just store the number 5.

Comment: if you are staring with `1` and incrementing it's size, it very much looks like you are just counting them - are you?

Comment: I assume (and hope) that this is just a simplified example.

Comment: It's just a simplified example. You can replace the v.add(v.size() + 1) with some other simple one-liner.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another alternative:

```
Set<Integer> set = m.computeIfAbsent (key , k -> new HashSet<> ());
set.add(set.size() + 1);
```

The only reason this is a two liner (instead of one) is the need to obtain the current size of the `Set` in order to decide which value to add to it.

Comment: The best so far

Answer (score 3):

Not a one-liner unfortunately but it does its magic and is also directly more readable (downside : it creates a new `HashSet<>()` everytime)

```
m.putIfAbsent(key, new HashSet<>());
// Solution 1 :
m.compute(key, (k, v) -> {v.add(v.size() + 1); return v;});
// Solution 2 :
Set<Integer> s = m.get(key);
s.add(s.size() + 1);
```

Or as proposed by @Thilo and inspired by @Eran

```
m.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(m.get(key).size() + 1);
```

The one liner is possible because it returns the value it computed as mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

There is even a similar example in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

> map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet()).add(v);

The little trade-off of the liner is the extra call to `m.get(key)` which is not happening with the solution of @Eran

Comment: or `computeIfAbsent` if you want to avoid creating all these HashSet you don't need.

Comment: Indeed, and then we'll have a one-liner :)

Comment: The second one is pretty nice. I didn't realize computeIfAbsent() returned the result of the function.

Comment: @BGRT However, it adds the (small) cost of running another lookup in the `Map` (`m.get(key)`), which can be avoided if you settle for a two liner.

Comment: @Eran Indeed, I'll add it and also add the Javadoc concerning the return value

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> v = m.getOrDefault(key, new HashSet<>());
v.add(v.size() + 1);
m.put(key, v);
```

Comment: Although this works, the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950387/466862) is better.